# How to set this Detail View Alpha 1.0 , non transparent in ios?

Tags: ios, view, alpha

When I click on Share button. Open Share_view. and its alpha 0.5 but I am add another view on Share view.

But I want to this view alpha 1.0 and its not transparent I want to see full white.

[See my Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwkg6.png)

I had try this, but this is not working at all:

```
[Detail_view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor White] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are adding Detail_view on Share_view, hence Share_view is the parent for your Detail_view.

Solution - 
Make Detail_view a subview of self.view, i.e

```
[self.view addSubview:Detail_view];
```

If you want Detail_view on Share_view, you can do this:

Don't set the alpha directly on the parent view. Instead use

```
[Share_view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
```

Now any child view can have its own color and will NOT be transparent.